# Most memory-efficient technique to isolate HTML received through an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is simple, however I do not know what terms to use to search for an answer. Is it significantly faster and more memory efficient to split a string containing a web page down to only the part I want before converting it to a DOM object, or is it better to convert the whole page and then select the piece? It is important that I use as little memory as possible because it is a very limited, very slow mobile device.

Comment: if your server is connected to Internet, you can use pipes of yahoo: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/

Comment: strings consume less memory than DOM trees. obviously.

Comment: That's what I thought. I was wondering if the difference between the methods was enough to really matter.